# A manhwa/manga about old wizard who got reincarnated after dying, and now he looks like Harry Potter

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

Genre: Reincarnation

This old wizard lives in an age where there is no sign of science. He seems to be living in the medieval age. He and his two servants are cooking food in the mountains. Both servants are oni, one male and one female. They had attacked the old sorcerer and lost to him a few years ago, and then they became his servants. They now live with him, disguised as humans. After a few years, the old wizard is attacked by other Oni for some reason. His two servants try to protect him as best as they could, but the old wizard dies and gets reincarnated. In the next chapter he is a high schooler who looks like Harry Potter. He is in the modern age now with everyone using smartphones. He was bullied for some reason on the school rooftop. After everyone left school, a small monster came out of a portal. He was going to fight the monster then the chapter ends. I am not sure this a manhwa or manga. There was mention of Oni which are Japanese monsters but the art style looked Korean. I think this is a manhwa. I can't remember the manga/ manhwa name anymore. Can anyone help me find this manga/manhwa?

Comment: How does he look like Harry Potter? Black hair with bangs? Round glasses? Lightning scar on his forehead? Bright green eyes?

Comment: I don't remember what type of glasses he wears he has black hair his face  looks similar to harry potters I don't remember if he have bangs or not

Comment: He don't have scar on his forehead

Comment: is this colored or not